# aws cli cloudwatch describe-alarms where alarm name is like "something"

Tags: json, bash, amazon-web-services, jq, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a bash array that contains a list of SQS queues:

```
sqsQueues=($(aws sqs list-queues | jq '.[]' --compact-output | sed 's/\[\|\]//g' | sed -E 's/"|,/ /g'))
```

Now I want to check the values in that array and see if I have any cloudwatch alerts that have a name matching the names of the SQS queues.

So essentially, I would like something like this:

```
aws cloudwatch describe-alarms --query "MetricAlarms[?AlarmName contains($filteredQueueName)]"
```

where `$filteredQueueName` is the name of the current queue I want to compare.

I know that `jq` code above is not valid. But I am not sure how to ask "Show me all cloudwatch alarms Where AlarmName *is LIKE* `$filteredQueueName`. I read about the command contains() on the `jq` manual page but I struggle to apply it in context.

Thanks

Comment: I think the syntax should be % aws cloudwatch describe-alarms --query 'MetricAlarms[?contains(AlarmName, $filteredQueueName) == ``true``]' true here is in single backticks.

Comment: @PankajSaini - it looks like the expression isn't valid:
aws cloudwatch describe-alarms --query "MetricAlarms[?contains(AlarmName, foo) == `true`]"

Bad value for --query MetricAlarms[?contains(AlarmName, foo) == ]: invalid token: Parse error at column 42, token "]" (RBRACKET), for expression:
"MetricAlarms[?contains(AlarmName, foo) == ]"

Comment: The backticks quote is making it not appear correctly in a comment. Let me add it as an answer and then you can check if this works for you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this script which fetches alarm configuration when **AlarmName** contains **Bill**:

```
pankaj@pankaj-mac TP % cat descalarm.sh 
filteredQueueName="Bill"
aws cloudwatch describe-alarms --query "MetricAlarms[?contains(AlarmName, \`${filteredQueueName}\`) == \`true\`]"
pankaj@pankaj-mac TP % ./descalarm.sh 
[
    {
        "AlarmName": "Billing Alarm",
        "AlarmArn": "arn:aws:cloudwatch:us-xx-1:xxxx:alarm:Billing Alarm",
        "AlarmDescription": "Send me an email if my bill goes above US$10",
        "AlarmConfigurationUpdatedTimestamp": "2019-12-07T05:16:57.795000+00:00",
        "ActionsEnabled": true,
        "OKActions": [],
        "AlarmActions": [
            "arn:aws:sns:us-xx-1:xxxx:Billing_Alarm"
        ],
        "InsufficientDataActions": [],
        "StateValue": "INSUFFICIENT_DATA",
        "StateReason": "Unchecked: Initial alarm creation",
        "StateUpdatedTimestamp": "2019-12-07T05:16:57.795000+00:00",
        "MetricName": "EstimatedCharges",
        "Namespace": "AWS/Billing",
        "Statistic": "Maximum",
        "Dimensions": [
            {
                "Name": "Currency",
                "Value": "USD"
            }
        ],
        "Period": 21600,
        "EvaluationPeriods": 1,
        "DatapointsToAlarm": 1,
        "Threshold": 10.0,
        "ComparisonOperator": "GreaterThanThreshold",
        "TreatMissingData": "missing"
    }
]
pankaj@pankaj-mac TP %
```

Another example fetching alarms with **AlarmName** containing **xxx**. Rightly so, no alarms are found and empty array is returned.

```
pankaj@pankaj-mac TP % cat descalarm.sh 
filteredQueueName="xxx"
aws cloudwatch describe-alarms --query "MetricAlarms[?contains(AlarmName, \`${filteredQueueName}\`) == \`true\`]"
pankaj@pankaj-mac TP % ./descalarm.sh 
[]
pankaj@pankaj-mac TP %
```

Comment: Hi @Pankaj Saini, thank you for your answer.  It works well.
Could you please explain your quotes:     \\`${filteredQueueName}\\`. 
  
Why it works with backticks ` ` , but doesn't work with single or double quotes?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I can assist in inspecting/debuging all elements in the array with `printf` or `echo` command:

```
 printf "%s\n" ${sqsQueues[@]}
```

The array start from `0`.

```
 echo "qsQueues[0]=${sqsQueues[0]}"
```

Iterating over the array:

```
for filteredQueueName in qsQueues; do
   echo "filteredQueueName=$filteredQueueName"
done
```

Hope this is helpful.